Getting 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' Message While Trying to Install shadcn
I am doing the Banking app course on JavaScript Mastery's YouTube channel.
At 9:52. when I enter the following command:
npx shadcn@latest init

I get this error message:
PS F:\JavaScript Mastery\jsm_banking> npx shadcn@latest      
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:215
  const resolvedOption = FSLegacyMainResolve(packageJsonUrlString, packageConfig.main, baseStringified);
                         ^

Error: Cannot find package 'C:\Users\MY\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d66c5096c7023bfb\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist\index.js' imported from C:\Users\MY\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d66c5096c7023bfb\node_modules\shadcn\dist\index.js
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:215:26)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:841:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:927:18)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1169:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:540:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:509:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:239:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:95:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}


How can I fix this issue?

Alright. I have found the fix! First, I had to enter this command: npm install -g shadcn. Then I run this command: npx shadcn@latest init. Then my issue got fixed!

I am facing this exact issue today, it comes out of nowhere whenever I try to add a new component. Found this solution, didn't work for me, but maybe it might work for you
The solution that worked for me at the end of the day was running the following commands:

npm cache clean --force
npx clear-npx-cache
npx shadcn add component_name (don't add @latest)

